# FormData send the same three keys with three different values

Tags: forms, vue.js

I need to achieve this using FormData.
[image]

So far I have tried formData.set and formData.append.

Both of them overwrite the key's value or add it if it does not exists.
const distributionChannels = []

```
  var bodyFormData = new FormData()
    distributionChannels.push('Push')
    distributionChannels.push('Sms')
    distributionChannels.push('Email')

  distributionChannels.forEach(element => {
    bodyFormData.set('distributionChannels', element)
    bodyFormData.append('distributionChannels', element)
  })
```

If I use them both then I get two duplicate keys with the same value.

Even if I try to 'hack' the system I still cannot choose three separate options out of two.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you have a loop that creates a NEW (`FormData.set()` creates new property everytime) property on every iteration and rewrites it right after.

Solution: All you need is append those values via `formData.append('distributionChannels', value)` in that loop. So on first iteration inexistent property will be created and on every iteration after the new value will be added to existed property.